# Animation is not very smooth when making a image slide effect using HTML canvas

Tags: html5-canvas

I want to make an image slide effect using HTML5 canvas. I am able to "slide" the image by translating the canvas and redrawing the image. However, during the slide process, the canvas cleared and the left of the image redrawn causes some flickering along the left side if the image.
Here is a demo link: http://codepen.io/make2514/pen/rLQwbz. Below is my script for canvas:

```
var img = new Image();
var imgLoaded = false;
img.src = "http://in5d.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/SHMNTYMETM.jpg"
img.onload = function(){
    imgLoaded = true;
};

var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');

function play() {

    push(canvas, img, function () {
        console.log('done');
    });
}

function push (canvas, canvasIn) {
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'); 

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    if (imgLoaded) {
      ctx.translate(5, 0);
    }
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    window.requestAnimationFrame(function () {
        push(canvas, img);
    });
}
```

I try to reduce the x-axis canvas translation to smaller value but the flickering is still there.

I would really appreciate any suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a lot of small bugs in your code.  You defined the `src` property of the image before its `onload` event, which won't ensure it is fired.  Your `push` function would run forever, but should end as soon as the image is off-screen, presumably.  You also made no use of the callback you were passing into `push` from `play`.  I added the callback as an argument and executed when `push` executes for the final time.  You also had a `canvas` and `canvasIn` argument, which weren't really necessary.  You hadn't even used `canvasIn`, but went with referring to `img` instead.  Therefore, I removed those arguments.  I also added an `xOff` variable to keep track of the state of the canvas to know when the animation finished.

```
var img = new Image();
var imgLoaded = false;
img.onload = function () {
    imgLoaded = true;
};
img.src = "http://in5d.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/SHMNTYMETM.jpg";
var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
var xOff = 0;

function play() {
    push(function () {
        console.log("done");
    });
}

function push (callback) {
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.translate(5, 0);
    if (xOff < img.width) {
        if(imgLoaded) {
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        }
        xOff+=5;
        window.requestAnimationFrame(function () {
            push(callback);
        });
    } else {
        callback();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your input! Could you suggest some changes that I could make to fix the flickering effect that still remains on the image left side?

Comment: Instead of using a fixed step size of 5px for the translate, you could instead use a length of time for the animation and extrapolate the step size from each frame, or abandon JavaScript and the canvas altogether and go with a CSS3 animation.

Comment: I believe the flickering effect is from jumping 5px every frame.  If you try 1px for instance, the effect would be less pronounced.